# Reporting Services dynamic chart width

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a bar chart that can display various number of bars depending on user multi-select. How do I get the bar chart to dynamically adjust to the number of bars being displayed? The only solutions I found online were dated 2008 and weren't good solutions either, surely there must be a proper way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify how you want it to adjust to the number of bars.  do you mean actually making the chart wider if there are more bars, or editing the bars themselves in some way?

Comment: Hi. Yes exactly. Right now the case is that the more bars the smaller they have to be in order to fit in the same static x-axis width. I would like the bars to have a static width and have the width of the chart adjust to the number of bars. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was about to rubbish such an idea, as it is known that you cannot dynamically change table sizes and locations, it seems Reporting Services is wonderfully inconsistent.

If you look in the Properties of the chart there is a field called `DynamicWidth`, which will, as suggested, dynamically change the width of the chart based on a value.

For example I have set a parameter called `Offset` to default to `10`.

You can then set the value of DynamicWidth to

```
=CStr(Parameters!Offset.Value) + "cm"
```

Then, as you change the Offset parameter, the width of the chart changes.

> `DynamicWidth = 10`
>
> [image]

And

> `DynamicWidth = 20`
>
> [image]

Now how you calculate the width to be meaningful and consistent is up to you (perhaps a permanent value for the size + (number of columns * column width)), but this should get you started.

Note that a `DynamicWidth` of `0` causes the report not to render.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much

Comment: (perhaps a permanent value for the size + (number of columns * column width))  what is the size? the size of the chart or the column?